# How can I effectively integrate Python FastAPI with Gremlin Python for Amazon Neptune database?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

Specifically, **I'm looking for guidance on managing connections, such as whether to open and close a connection for each request or use a single connection for the entire application**. I'm aware that if WebSocket connections are not closed properly,**Neptune terminates idle connections after 20-25 minutes.** Moreover, reaching the concurrent WebSocket connection limit results in HTTP 429 errors. What strategies can I implement to handle connections and avoid these issues?

Or **Alternate Strategy is to use Lambda AWS Lambda functions**, each dedicated to distinct tasks and APIs, to connect with an Amazon Neptune database using Gremlin Python.

I have created a Sample app

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks, Depends
import asyncio
import websockets
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
import queue
import time

app = FastAPI()

# Neptune Configuration
neptune_endpoint = 'your-neptune-endpoint'
neptune_port = 8182

# Define the minimum and maximum number of connections in the pool
min_connections = 5
max_connections = 20

# Connection timeout in seconds
connection_timeout = 15 * 60

# Create a queue object to store the connections
connection_pool = queue.Queue(maxsize=max_connections)

# Dictionary to track the usage status of connections
connection_usage = {}

# Get an event loop object
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Dependency to get a connection from the pool or create a new one if needed
async def get_connection():
    try:
        # Try to get a connection from the queue
        ws = connection_pool.get(block=False)
        connection_usage[ws] = True  # Mark the connection as in use
        return ws
    except queue.Empty:
        # If the queue is empty, create a new connection
        ws = await create_connection()
        connection_usage[ws] = True  # Mark the connection as in use
        return ws

# Dependency to return a connection to the pool or mark it as available
async def return_connection(ws):
    if ws in connection_usage:
        connection_usage[ws] = False  # Mark the connection as available
        try:
            # Put the connection back in the queue without blocking
            connection_pool.put(ws, block=False)
        except queue.Full:
            # If the queue is full, close the connection
            await close_connection(ws)

# Dependency to close a connection
async def close_connection(ws):
    if ws in connection_usage:
        await ws.close()
        del connection_usage[ws]

# Define a function to create a websocket connection with Neptune
async def create_connection():
    ws = await asyncio.wait_for(websockets.connect(f'wss://{neptune_endpoint}:{neptune_port}/gremlin'), timeout=15)
    connection_usage[ws] = True  # Mark the connection as in use
    return ws

# Define a function to execute a Gremlin query
async def execute_query(query: str):
    ws = await get_connection()
    remote_connection = DriverRemoteConnection(ws, 'g')
    try:
        g = Graph().traversal().withRemote(remote_connection)
        result = g.V().hasLabel(query).toList()  # Modify the query as needed
        return result
    finally:
        await return_connection(ws)

# Background task to periodically check and replace connections
async def check_connection_timeouts():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # Check every 1 minute
        current_time = time.time()
        for ws, in_use in connection_usage.items():
            if not in_use and current_time - ws.creation_time > connection_timeout:
                await close_connection(ws)
                new_ws = await create_connection()
                connection_pool.put(new_ws)
                new_ws.creation_time = current_time

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    # Fill the connection pool with the minimum number of connections
    await fill_connection_pool()
    # Start the background task to check connection timeouts
    loop.create_task(check_connection_timeouts())

@app.get('/')
async def execute_gremlin_query(query: str):
    result = await execute_query(query)
    return {"result": result}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, the recommendation is to share the connection pool (essentially `g`) between threads in your application rather than open and close a new connection each time. You do have some control over the size of the connection pool created and the number of worker threads assigned to it.

As you mentioned, when working with Amazon Neptune, there are times where you may need to recreate the connection; such as if it is closed due to being idle, or something like a failover happens and the IP address of the server changes.

If you used AWS Lambda Functions, each Lambda function would need its own connection, but that connection can be maintained across multiple invocations.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks a bunch for the excellent explanation! I totally get how sharing the connection pool between threads can boost control and efficiency – smart move!

You've got me curious about using AWS Lambda functions too. Can you dive into the pros and cons of this approach compared to handling connections right in the app? And if you've got any tips on dealing with Neptune's failovers and IP changes, I'm all ears.

Your guidance has been a game-changer, and I'm looking forward to implementing these strategies for my project. Big thanks once again!

Comment: Perhaps start by reading the text and example code [available here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions.html)